# Writing a product as a sum of cubes of differences

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

While thinking about another problem, I ended up wondering about the following curiosity: let $A$ be a finite set of real numbers and let $a,b,c,d,e,f \in A$. Can we write the expression

$$3(a-b)(c-d)(e-f)$$

as a finite sum of terms of the form $(x-y)^3$, where $x,y \in A$?

For instance, for squares we can always write 
$$(a_1-b_1)^2 + (a_1-b_2)^2 - (b_1-b_2)^2 = 2(a_1-b_1)(a_1-b_2),$$
which after more playing around leads to
$$(a_1-b_2)^2 - (a_2-b_1)^2 - (a_1 - b_1)^2 - (a_2-b_2)^2 = 2(a_1-a_2)(b_1-b_2).$$

Similarly, I'd something like
$$(a-b)^3 + (b-c)^3 + (c-a)^3 = 3(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$$
to lead to an identity for $3(a-b)(c-d)(e-f)$.

PS. Added the linear algebra tag since maybe there are some hidden algebra tricks lying in the background (e.g. one can prove the last identity by evaluating a determinant).

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible.  Note that by choosing $a,b,c,d,e,$ and $f$ to be algebraically independent and $A=\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$, it suffices to show that $3(a-b)(c-d)(e-f)$ is not a finite sum of terms of the form $(x-y)^3$ (where $x$ and $y$ are each one of the six variables) as a formal polynomial in the six variables.  But no expression of the form $(x-y)^3$ has a term with three different variables, whereas the expression $3(a-b)(c-d)(e-f)$ does (in fact, every term has three different variables).  So $3(a-b)(c-d)(e-f)$ cannot be a linear combination of expressions of the form $(x-y)^3$ as a formal polynomial.